# Interpreting precision/recall results from a LogisticRegression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, precision-recall

I computed a word vector model on medical reports on a critical disease and run a logistic regression on a binary classifier. Text data is labeled with 1=successful and 0=non-successful for the true outcome of the treatment. I train with 90% of my data and test on 10%. The dataset contains about 30% successful and 70% unsuccessful cases (N= ca. 20,000).

Now, I got following results from my `scikit-learn` function:

```
LogR = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C= 1.0, max_iter=100, n_jobs=1, tol=0.0001)
LogR = LogR.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = LogR.predict(x_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, digits=3))

             precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0.0     0.6197    0.9543    0.7514      3413
        1.0     0.3305    0.0371    0.0667      2076

avg / total     0.5103    0.6074    0.4924      5489
```

I would like to make sure, how to *interpret* the results. In particular, what it implies, *practically*. Note that I looked into the theory of "[precision vs. recall tradeoff](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/CuONQ/trading-off-precision-and-recall)", the basic definition of accuracy, precision, and recall, as well as F-score weights.

As I interpret the results,

- Overall accuracy seems like flipping a coin, or, as the averaged F-score suggests, even a bit worse.
- The model has a higher precision in classifying unsuccessful treatments ("0",61%). In particular the 95% recall suggests that it almost does not miss out any of the unsuccessful treatments in the whole test sample.
- However, the model is almost not able to identify successful cases ("1"). It only captures about 33% of the potential candidates and includes many false positives. In addition, the proportion of true positive classifications that are true positive is very, very low (3%).

Assuming you would be a doctor, would these prepositions be correct:

- Intution on h**igh precision, low recall**: How many treatments are predicted correctly, at the risk to include a few false positives?
- Intution on **low precision, high recall**: How many treatments are predicted correctly, at the risk to include a few false negatives? (i.e. how high are the chances to have a prediction for a successful outcomes, whereas truth turns out to be non-successful)

It would be great to have a bit of feedback, or correction of my interpretations.

Comment: Did you try plotting ROC curve, ROC curve will give better indication if your classifier is better than flipping the coin.

Answer (score 1):

The logistic model's job is direct probability estimation.  Don't use any accuracy measure that requires categorizing the estimated probabilities.  More details are [here](http://www.fharrell.com/2017/03/damage-caused-by-classification.html).  The $c$-index (concordance probability; AUROC) can help but it supplements rather than replaces measures based on the predicted probabilities and log-likelihood.  It would also be advisable to read about optimum decision making and how it uses probabilities coupled with a utility function and does not pre-categorize predicted probabilities.  This relates to minimizing expected loss/cost.  The ROC curve doesn't help, as it invites the analyst to choose a cutpoint that is divorced from the actual utility function.